# SignalR Failed to fetch connection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm trying to create an interactive whiteboard using SignalR, and I'm facing the following issue:
[image]

Here is my following code:

tsx file:

```
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";

const hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("http://localhost:5001/whiteboard")
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
  .build();

hubConnection
  .start()
  .then(() => console.log(hubConnection!.state))
  .catch((e) => console.log("Error SignalR: ", e));
```

and for the Startup.cs file:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
        }));
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSignalR();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<WhiteboardHub>("/whiteboard");
        });
    }
```

I've installed @microsoft/signalR for client side and I'm using netcoreapp5.0

Thanks in advance!

Update: It was a problem with port config for API and client app.

Comment: By default apps are hosted at **http**://localhost:5000 and **https**://localhost:5001. Looks like you might be mixing the https port with an http connection.

Comment: @Brennan when my app starts, using npm start, it's opened to localhost:3000. If I'm trying to switch to localhost:5000, I receive This website can't be reached

Comment: I was talking about your server app.

Comment: I'm very new to this and very confused, but they're not the same app, the client one and server app?

Comment: @Brennan you're kinda right, I've managed to start the app on port 5000, so it can comunicate, but now I'm receiving Error 404 not found (Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: Not Found and Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Not Found)

Comment: Could you please share the 404 error message? Which page is not found? or Signlar reference?

Comment: @BrandoZhang it's ok now, I had a problem with server config and mixed react and server port